# Do hairless cats need bath? If yes then do they need some special hairless cat soap?

Tags: cats, bathing

Do hairless cats need bath? How often? Do I need special hairless cat soap?

Any advice is appreciated.

Comment: I wouldn't say this is a duplicate question. Because this question specifically asked about 'hairless' cats, and they DO have different needs. see this link: https://www.petmd.com/cat/breeds/c_ct_sphynx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cats do not need a bath at all unless they get something on them like grease or oil and potentially toxic substances.

So unless this is the case you do not need to give any cat a bath.

Giving cats a bath will remove the natural protective oils in the skin of your cat and may cause serious skin problems.